# Find index of a row in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given m x n numpy array

```
X = np.array([
  [1, 2],
  [10, 20],
  [100, 200]
])
```

how to find index of a row, i.e. [10, 20] -> 1?

n could any - 2, 3, ..., so I can have n x 3 arrays

```
Y = np.array([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [10, 20, 30],
  [100, 200, 300]
])
```

so I need to pass a vector of size n, in this case n=3, i.e a vector [10, 20, 30] to get its row index 1? Again, n could be of any value, like 100 or 1000.

Numpy arrays could be big, so I don't want to convert them to lists to use .index()

Comment: In your example you have `[10, 20]` then you refer to a vector `[10, 20, 30]`: is the query tensor you are using to find the index of variable size?

Comment: My thoughts that `np.where((X[:,0] == 10) & (X[:,1] == 20))` do the job, but I don't know how to make a condition to handle arbitrary number n of elements in a vector, i.e. how given a vector `[10, 20, 30]` automatically get a condition like `(Y[:,0] == 10) & (Y[:,1] == 20) & (Y[:,2] == 30)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case that the query array contains duplicate rows that you are looking for, the function below returns multiple indices in such case.

```py
def find_rows(source, target):
    return np.where((source == target).all(axis=1))[0]

looking = [10, 20, 30]

Y = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [10, 20, 30],
              [100, 200, 300],
              [10, 20, 30]])

print(find_rows(source=Y, target=looking)) # [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.equal`, which will broadcast and compare row vector against each row of the original array, and if all elements of a row are equal to the target, the row is identical to the target:

```
import numpy as np
np.flatnonzero(np.equal(X, [10, 20]).all(1))
# [1]

np.flatnonzero(np.equal(Y, [10, 20, 30]).all(1))
# [1]
```

Comment: @Sengiley you should look into [boolean masking](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=boolean%20mask#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) as an alternate solution as it is a very powerful technique.

Comment: @Sengiley You're welcome. Glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function as follow:

```
def get_index(seq, *arrays):
    for array in arrays:
        try:
            return np.where(array==seq)[0][0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

then:

```
>>>get_index([10,20,30],Y)
1
```

Or with just indexing:

```
>>>np.where((Y==[10,20,30]).all(axis=1))[0]
1
```

Comment: yes, but it's iteration which is not vectorized, thus is slow

I want to make use of numpy indexing

Comment: unfortunately, your indexing example is incorrect as it finds indices of individual vector elements

`Y = np.array([
  [10, 2, 3],
  [10, 20, 30],
  [100, 20, 30]
])`
so 
`np.where(Y[:,:]==[10, 20, 30])`

gives

`(array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]))`